# An unhandled exception occurred: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID - "ng add @ngrx/store" in Angular 13

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

After the upgrade to Angular 13, when I try to add NgRx to the project with schematics (`ng add @ngrx/store`) I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing the `latest` version of the `@ngrx/store` fixed it:

```
ng add @ngrx/store@latest
```